# Responsive menu adjustments

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

SO I have modified the bootstrap responsive menu to close when you click outside of it. The problem I have is that when you click a link with in a submenu of that main menu it closes the submenu - ideally I would like to keep it open. The reason being as some of those links are modals and therefore I would like to preserve the state of the page.

Example here:

plnkr.co/edit/arGrZ8onXsHYNjAIOeQx?p=preview

If you click the dropdown menu and then the Action link you will see that the submenu closes.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line of code on your html file or load the script from your js file.

```
<script>
$(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
if( $(e.target).is('a') && $(e.target).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle' ) {
    $(this).collapse('hide');
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: This will close the menu!

Comment: Sorry maybe my question isnt clear. If you look at my example I already have the main nav behavior I want. The problem is I want to keep the submenu OPEN when I click one of it's links.

Comment: OK! I did get that right. Now I'm on mobile device will take a look on that as soon as I get to a desktop.